# Prove that for all $n\ge1$, a complete graph of n vertices contains k-cliques for k $\in \{1,...,n\}$

Tags: graph-theory

My professor's tip was to use mathematical induction.

My understanding of the question at first is that given a complete graph with n vertices (denoted $K_n$), prove that if you remove one of the vertices of the graph (so you get a subgraph), your subgraph will be a complete graph (a clique).

But, as I dissect the question, I'm starting to wonder if my understanding of the question is correct?

This is my proof so far:

We need to prove that given a complete subgraph $K_{n+1}$, it's subgraph $K_n$ is also a complete graph, or by definition, a clique.

(Base Case: n = 1)
If n = 1, then k $\in \{1\}$ This is a graph with 1 vertex. Indeed, a graph with one node, denoted by $K_1$ is a complete graph.

(Inductive Case: n >= 1)
Assume $K_{n+1}$ is a complete graph with $n + 1$ vertices. We claim that removing one vertex from $K_{n+1}$ will result into $K_n$, which is also a complete graph. This would imply that $K_n$ is a clique. From the base case, we already know that $K_n$ is a complete graph.

We simply need to prove that a graph is still complete even if you remove a vertex, v from $K_{n+1}$. That is,

$K_{n+1}$ - v = $K_n$, for v $\in K_{n+1}$

${n+1}\choose{2}$ - $(n-1)$ = ${n}\choose{2}$

However, I can't prove this. I end up with:

$\frac{n^2-n+2}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Is my understanding of the question correct? And is my proof correct, or in the right direction?

Comment: The vertex $v$ has a degree $n$ in $K_{n+1}$

Comment: Good catch. Thank you. Is my understanding of the question correct though? I'm proving that the subgraph of a complete graph is also complete, but I'm not sure if that's what's meant by "k-cliques"

Comment: You proved that $K_{n+1}$ has $K_n$ as it's subgraph. By the hypothesis you can use that $K_n$ has $k$-clique for every $1 \le k \le n$ and so $K_{n+1}$ must have it too. Obvously $K_{n+1}$ is itself a $(n+1)$-clique, which should finish your proof.

In general you're proof is perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

The question is trivial. Any two vertices of a complete graph are adjacent, so  *any* subset of its vertices induces a clique.